# How is brick size decided?

Tags: masonry

I am always fascinated to watch construction on field as it  helps me to build my knowledge deeper. The answer to a question what I am looking upto is HOW is the brick size decided ? Like in India we have standarized size of 19×9×9 cm But actually how only this size became standard?

Comment: 19cm length = 20cm length with the plaster in between bricks (hope plaster is the correct word)  same in height.. I'm building in belgium with bricks 39x19x14 als a standard size.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick#Optimal_dimensions.2C_characteristics.2C_and_strength

Comment: You are getting me wrong! Question is how the size of 19cm was decided?

Comment: fyi the wiki page actually has a good treatment of brick dimension  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick   (The basic size is driven by the need to conveniently handle with one hand.)  The choice of exact dimension, (19 vs 20) is no doubt just a matter of local historical custom

Comment: @agentp Oh you are right.! I didnt think of that. Thanks